# How to move an issue from existing team project collection to other?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We have 2 team project collection say 'Colleciton 1' and 'Collection 2' and using TFS 2010.
Each team does not have access to the other project collection except admins.

Support team files all the issues in collection 'Collection 1'. Another team works on the issue and decides whether the issue will be solved by team working on 'Colleciton 1' or 'Collection 2'.

If the issue has to be assigned to 'Collection 2' team, what change should be done in the issue? Is there a way, we can change the team project collection of the issue to 'Collection 2'?

I tried to do it from backend (Database) in 'WorkItemsAre' table but didn't found any column related to the project collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [integration platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) for these kind of things

Comment: I found another named Hemi - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlee/archive/2006/11/20/work-item-moving-tool-is-back.aspx but it will create a copy of the work item and then delete the old one. I don't think this is a good approach. I will check the link you provided.